# M2 - Get stock quantity on product detail page

Tags: magento2, stock, quantity

I need to get the stock quantity on the product detail page. I'm not an expert in Magento but I was being told that using the objectmanager is not a good idea, but in almost every example I find I see the use of the objectmanager.

Is there somehow another way to get the stock quantity on the product detail page?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get stock qty on product details page using below code.

```
$stockItem = $product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem();
print_r($stockItem->getQty());
```

Let me know if I you need further help

Comment: Yes, it's working! :)

Comment: great @n00bly happy coding :)